# text returning null from a different page

Tags: android, flutter, text

im a beginner at coding flutter and im having a problem.

The text is returning null as you can see from the screenshot, [if the user is authenticated with the firebase database, it shows the name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XiiT.jpg)

**BUT** if they register then it takes them to the main page, to which it shows **[null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNWv8.jpg)** instead of their profile name.

here is the code where the displayName is called

```
          Container(
            height: 165.0,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset("images/user_icon.png",
                      height: 65.0, width: 65.0),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 16.0,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        //THIS IS WHERE THE displayName is called
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Brand-Bold"),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 6.0,
                      ),
                      Text("Visit Profile"),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Here is the code where it goes to the MainScreen from the RegistrationScreen

```
  void _navigateToNextScreen(BuildContext context) {
    firebaseUser.updateProfile(displayName: enteredName);
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
  }
```

i dont understand what i am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: after registration you must call to authenticate (login) before you can use FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser. Register doesn't mean authenticated

Comment: can you elaborate on that please.. how can i authenticate the current registered user..